# AngularJS - model changes not updating the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

AngularJS Classic: Im changing my Model on `ng-click` an the view is not updating. I thought a simply `$scope.$apply()` would update but i'm not getting it working. I suppose I'm not setting `$apply()` in the right place or something like that.

**Example:** [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8rREFdLKvznaNLlaj6Hm)

The name of the Object is changed on Press button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your `explorerObject` one more time after clicking, cause it is still pointing on your previous object:

```
 $scope.click = function () {
    ExplorerService.setExplorerObject({
      selected : {
        name: 'Defined Now !',
        id: 'id',
        timestamp: 'timestamp'
      },
      templateURL: 'views/beispiel.html'
    });
     $scope.explorerObject = ExplorerService.getExplorerObject(); // <--- here
  }
```

Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/UWE7o3mtAzY3xzYRWfkf?p=preview

**After question' edit:**

You can use `$watch` in your second controller:

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, ExplorerService) {

  $scope.$watch(function(){
      return ExplorerService.getExplorerObject();
  },function(n,o){
      $scope.explorerObject = ExplorerService.getExplorerObject(); 
  },true)

});
```

Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/8mZO5kZmTrqwHKnxtBSd?p=preview

Or use a `$broadcast` approach, like:

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, ExplorerService) {

  $scope.explorerObject = ExplorerService.getExplorerObject(); 

  $scope.$on("EXPLORER_OBJECT_CHANGED" ,function(event,obj){ 
      $scope.explorerObject = obj;
  });    

});
```

And in your service add: `$rootScope.$broadcast("EXPLORER_OBJECT_CHANGED", explorerObject);`

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/9WKypJTb0wViQZ01m9TN?p=preview

Comment: I'm sorry that my example was not exactly representing the problem I have. I've updated it now. Thank you for your answer. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8rREFdLKvznaNLlaj6Hm)

Comment: @strangfeld i'm not very expert in performances , but i think that  `$scope.$watch` is more expensive because seems to me that it is running on every digest cycle it means that `ExplorerService.getExplorerObject()` will run all the time. On the other hand , `$rootScope.$broadcast` will run only when `setExplorerObject` will run, and it makes architecture "less coupled" , so in me eyes this approach is more preferred